# The checkbox is not worked ,in jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Hello: i have problem whit the checkbox ,i tried to make a button when it's checked its enable otherwise it's disable but it's not worked well, when i chekcked it enable but when i unchecked  that it show the button enable .looking forward for yours  help.

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('#agree').change(function(){
       state = $('#agree').attr('value');
       if ( state == 'on'){
          $('#continue').removeAttr('disabled');
       }else if (state == '') {
          $('#continue').attr('disabled','disabled');
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: Please show a complete working example, including your HTML code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking a checkbox with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/checking-a-checkbox-with-jquery)

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html >
<html lang = "en">
<head> <meta charset = "utf-8">
 
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="addclass.css"> -->
 <title> removeAttr</title>
</head>
<body> 

   <p ><input id = "agree" type = "checkbox" value = 'on'>I Agree</p><br>
  <input type = "submit" value = "Continue" id = "continue" disabled = "disabled">      

  <script type="text/javascript " src = "JQ.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src = "removeattr.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 1):

You are testing the checkbox's value to determine its state. However, its value does not change (natively) when checked or unchecked. I suggest referencing JavaScript's `checked` property, instead. See the list of properties at [HTML Input Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement).

In the example below, I'm using `this.checked` to reference the status of the checkbox that has triggered the "change" event. I'm also using a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to set the button's `disabled` property accordingly.

```js
jQuery('#agree').change(function() {
  jQuery('#continue').prop('disabled', this.checked ? false : true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="agree" />Click To Enable</label>
<button id="continue" type="button" disabled="disabled">A Button</button>
```

Comment: Thank you it's worked but i swap the place of true and false , Thank you very much for your Help.

Comment: Oh, yes I see in your question you wanted the button enabled when the checkbox is checked. I updated my code for consistency.

Answer (score 0):

After getting positive answer from you all i did it and now it works well .

```
 $('#agree').change(function() {

 $('#cont').prop('disabled', this.checked ? false : true);
 });  //this is the css code and the html code is in down 

  <!DOCTYPE html >
  <html lang = "en">
  <head> <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <title> removeAttr</title>
    </head>
 <body> 

 <p ><input id = "agree" type = "checkbox">I Agree</p><br>
 <input type = "submit" value = "Continue" id = "continue" disabled ="disabled">      

  <script type="text/javascript " src = "JQ.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src = "removeattr.js"></script> 
  </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you better use toggleClass instead.

```
$('input').on('change',function(){
  $('button').toggleClass('disabled');
});
$('button.disabled').on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: `'disabled'` is an attribute, not a class, so this wouldn't have the same behavior.